# django except matching query does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm trying to use try and except in django; everything work perfect if the user exist but if the user doesn't exist instead of returning NULL; my function keep returning:

```
Userprofile matching query does not exist.
```

I know the user is not exist in table; I just want to not return anything instead of showing error page.

```
from django import template

from album.models import Album

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('album/user_album.html')

def userAlbumFunction(id):

    try:
        albums = Album.objects.filter(user_id = id)
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
        albums = None

    return {'albums' : albums}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django 1.3 UserProfile matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477925/django-1-3-userprofile-matching-query-does-not-exist)

Comment: no my problem is only for except

Comment: Can you please share your full code here? The exception may be `ObjectDoesNotExist`, or `ModelName.DoesNotExist`, or something else.

Comment: The execution will never reach to the ***`except` ...*** clause since Django will not raise a `DoesNotExist` exception while accessing the **`.filter(...)`** method @im-learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    albums = Album.objects.get(user_id = id)
except Album.DoesNotExist:
    albums = None
    pass
```